# Counting occurrences of specific column value compared to total count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing orders that can have 5 different statuses (11, 12, 14, 22, 24). I want to count the amount of status '12' (failed orders) occurrences and divide it by the total number of status counts (total number of orders).

Here's how my table looks:

```
status_id | restaurant
----------------------
11        | rest1
11        | rest1
12        | rest2
12        | rest3
12        | rest1
14        | rest1
24        | rest1
22        | rest1
```

I'd like to have the following (percentage is as an example)

```
status_id | restaurant | perc_of_status_id_12
---------------------------------------------
11        | rest1      | 10%
11        | rest1      | 10%
12        | rest2      | 5%
12        | rest3      | 11%
12        | rest1      | 10%
14        | rest1      | 10%
24        | rest1      | 10%
22        | rest1      | 10%
```

So the calculation for the last column should be:

```
Count of status id 12 for restaurantX / total number of orders
```

It would be even more perfect if it would be proportional to the total number of orders for restaurantX. For example, a restaurant receiving 1 order and failing 1 has a fail rate of 100%, but a restaurant receiving 100 orders and failing 5 has a fail rate of 5%. However, the restaurant with 5 failed orders should be prioritized. I don't really know how to incorporate that at the moment, perhaps assign a weight based on the total number of orders. If anyone has an idea about it, it would be much appreciated.

With weighting the table would look like this:

```
status_id | restaurant | perc_of_status_id_12 | weighted
--------------------------------------------------------
11        | rest1      | 10%                  | 10% * weight
11        | rest1      | 10%                  | 
12        | rest2      | 5%                   | 
12        | rest3      | 11%                  | 
12        | rest1      | 10%                  | 
14        | rest1      | 10%                  | 
24        | rest1      | 10%                  | 
22        | rest1      | 10%                  |
```

I tried playing around a bit with COUNT, but I can't figure it out. I tried this:

```
 ROUND((COUNT(CASE WHEN o.status_id = '12' THEN 1 END) * 100)::numeric / COUNT(CASE WHEN o.status_id IN ('11','12','14','22','24') THEN 1 END, 2)) AS fail_perc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FILTER` clause for an aggregate:

```
COUNT(status_id) FILTER (WHERE status_id = 12) / CAST(COUNT(status_id) AS float4)
```

For older PostgreSQL versions you can use `CASE` instead:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN status_id = 12 THEN 1 END) / CAST(COUNT(status_id) AS float4)
```

Comment: This does not give an error, but it only returns a 1 (fail) or a 0 (not fail). I basically want to count ALL occurrences of status id 12 for restaurantX divided by ALL orders combined.

Comment: @Mischa Yes, and that's what this does. Counts all status=12, and counts all entries. You'll want to `GROUP BY restaurant`. If you find it more readable you can use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` in the old-version `CASE` approach. If `status_id` can be null, use `count(*)` not `count(status_id)` for the denominator.

Comment: thank you for the help! Unfortunately it still does not do what I want. I have to add more columns to the GROUP BY because of my query. I have to put the following GROUP BY order_date, order_id, restaurant. I suppose that's the reason why it doesn't work as I want to.

Comment: @Mischa You should provide a complete example, then. This addresses the question as written. I suggest posting a new, more complete question with sample data as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, showing all the relevant fields, and complete expected output that reflects the whole situation.